# Is there a politer way of asking: Would you like?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Is there a politer or more formal way of asking: *Would you like … ?*

As when offering something (a glass of wine for instance), to someone of higher category. When extreme etiquette is required.

Comment: "Would you like a glass of wine" is perfectly suitable for the most formal settings.  Unlike many languages, English does not have any pronouns which may be used to show greater respect (cf French tu vs vous, or Hindi aap vs tum).

Comment: It's of a Jeeves register (when used without opening discussion): 'Might I suggest ...'; 'May I get you ...?' is not quite as rarified.

Answer (score 5):

'Would you care for a glass of wine?' is probably how Jeeves would have made the offer. Most members of the British polite class, in 2013, would do the same. It is the sort of thing taught at places like Cheltenham Ladies College.