# I would need 3 more sheets. (of paper)

Tags: grammar

A student is responsible for collecting sheets handed out in class for those students who are absent. This is what is often said to me as I'm handing out the sheets. I've always corrected them by stating that "need" is a state verb and in this instance should be in the simple present. It's an immediate need.

My colleague (a native-speaker), however, just argued that you could very well say "would need" in this context.

Is "would need" acceptable in this context and is the reason because it's conditional?

> I would need 3 more sheets (because 3 students are missing and I have to put 3 in the missing-student's binder for them.)

Comment: @KillingTime. Maybe it's just an AE vs BE thing, but I think it's acceptable to write just "native-speaker" instead of "a native-speaker" in parentheses. :-)

Comment: ... Unmarked << native speaker >> (check the usual spelling) is acceptable; putting it in scare quotes hints to me that this native speaker may have failed GCSE English or equivalent. // 'I'd be needing .../I would be needing ...' in this usage (= 'I need' semantically) sound like examples of Irish English, or pirate-speak, to my ear. // But "I need ..." _can_ (as well as in the statement of fact sense) be used with the force of a request or even a demand if doing an Oliver (asking for more). "I'll need ..." etc is an appropriate hedged-for-politeness form that _is_ available.

Comment: You should write numbers in English.

Comment: *I would like three more sheets* is an idiomatic usage of *would* to more politely express *I want three more sheets*. You could, in theory, say *I would need three more sheets*, but that would be unusual, and it would move from politeness to the hypothetical: *I would need 3 more sheets (if I am to finish the assignment).*

Comment: I agree with what @Tinfoil hat said. It's a polite way of saying it, more polite than simply saying, "I need."

Comment: Say my boss tells me to go and pick something up for him from the store, only he doesn't know that I got a ride to work, that I didn't drive, like I usually do, so I don't have any way to do that for him, but with him being an authority figure, I don't feel I can tell him no or make any outright demands, so I cushion my response with politeness, saying, "I would need a car," which informs him of the need and then politely defers to his authority in how to proceed, so maybe he meets that need by lending me his car or whatever or doesn't by telling me to figure it out or telling me to forget it.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth  I just realized my mistake: hyphenating native speaker. I mixed it up with native-English speaker.  I find your reference to failing GCSE English impertinent. Where are your manners?

Comment: @tchrist  It's a style, an agreed-upon convention to write out 0-10. But I'm just transcribing dialogue here and I think it's acceptable to write the digit. :-)

Comment: I neglected to say that this happens as I'm standing in front of the class or directly in front of the student. I agree with Tinfoil that the would makes the request hypothetical, which I don't think it is.

Comment: @Benjamin  I appreciate the scenario you've presented and would also use the polite would in that case. But I see a difference to the scenario I've given. There isn't a distance in time when I'm standing in front of the student compared to your scenario. The task has been known since the begining of the semester, so it's the same thing every day. My native-English speaker gut feeling tells me "I would need" doesn't fit in this case and I'm looking for a grammatical explanation to justify my point of view.

Comment: "would need" is polite when you're offering someone the option of satisfying the need or not. But if the teacher intends to give you the sheets, and only needs to know how many, just say "I need 3 sheets".

Comment: @Barmar  This contribution fits to my situation exactly. The student is required to satisfy the need because collecting the sheets for absent students is their required task for the week. Thank you!

Comment: See also [why do would and could make questions polite](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/568695/why-do-would-and-could-make-questions-polite), [we would ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449939/polite-request-we-would-ask), [would you like](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134909/is-there-a-politer-way-of-asking-would-you-like).

Comment: @Barmar Even if someone is paid to do something for you, or is otherwise obligated to help, it's still good manners to make a request in a polite way, e.g. saying "please" or phrasing it politely with "could" or "would".

Comment: @StuartF Maybe it's cultural, but in America I can't imagine anyone taking offense at someone saying "I need 3 more sheets to do what you asked." In fact, I would expect the instructor to apologize for not giving him enough sheets. "Sorry, here are the rest of the sheets."

Comment: "I would need three more sheets of paper" comes across as ex-colonial English, or as a rather pretentious hedged form. "Can/Could I please have three more sheets of paper./?" is more idiomatic (the 'could' and questioning tone choices adding further politeness).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Thank you for considering this old post of mine. My sentiments exactly—a pretentious, hedged form. ex-colonial English :-)  I like your suggestion: Can/Could I please ....  Yet, it's still tedious when someone has to say this every day for 9 months in my classes.  "I need 3 more sheets, Ms. ...." is polite and to the point, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Yes, context (here repetitiveness) often changes optimal style.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, here in Canada, it's generally normal to say "I would need" in an informal context, either to communicate doubt (there is a possibility that he/she might not need it in the end) or to convey that the student is not entitled to receive it, or even just to be polite. However, I wouldn't use "would need" in the context of the dialogue in formal writing.

Comment: In the situation I have presented, there is no possibility that the student won't need the sheets. It's a weekly duty that one student collects the homework sheets for those who are absent and puts them in a binder. It's a necessity in our situation. The student has to simply request the number of sheets necessary. My standpoint is that "would need" is superfluous and irrelevant for this need.

Comment: It's certainly possible to use "would" for politeness, so as to not be demanding something. Saying "I need such-and-such" could sound rather rude. It's perhaps superfluous but the essence of politeness is that it's not necessary to say please and thank you, but is done to be polite.

Comment: "Would need" might be superfluous in your opinion or generally, but might still be acceptable or up to the student's discretion.

Answer (score -2):

I assume the context is:

Student: "Can I have the sheets?"

You: "Yes. Here they are."

Student: "How many are there?"

You: "Twenty."

Student: "I **will** need three more." / *"I would need three more."

I think your student is becoming confused with the German "möchte" = would like.